# Uneven pixel display

Tags: css, reactjs, pixel, screen-resolution

[image]

I'm sorry I can't even describe the issue expressively, I'm facing this issue where these numbers on screen don't appear on the same line, even though they have the same height, same font-size, and same line height.

Increasing the font-size gradually seem to be fixing the issue at font-sizes of multiples of 3, otherwise it would still have this annoying offset. As if the issue is only about browser trying its best to approximate where this pixel should be but failing slightly.

This issue happens only on Firefox, the same component seems to work just fine on Chrome.

You can view the element further here https://ant.design/components/badge

Comment: Is this something like `10` font is totally different?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Not fully getting your question?

Comment: if the font supports multiples of 3 only, that's what you'll have to use if you have to stick with the font.

Comment: @iLuvLogix Unfortunately that is not possible, and even with that it is not enough, because all other numbers have the same issue.

Comment: @Webber I understand that there are workarounds, but our tasks are quite strict and we cannot edit things without a requirement. This is why I'm more interested in knowing why this is happening rather than just patching it anyway it comes.

Answer (score 2):

Use another font for the number.

Ant design badge creates all the numbers from 0-10 to display animations. Those are hidden, but visible in dom above / below the badge, but hidden by overflow. If you adjust manually the font size, you need to fix the line height / number height too, so that all the invisible numbers align properly.

[image: This is what badge has in the DOM]

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option. I have to stick with the same font. Plus, why is it even happening in the first place?